# Equivalent of permview.exe in .NET 4?

Tags: .net, security, .net-4.0

Is there any equivalent of [permview.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06251f13%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in .NET 4?

A search on [permview on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=permview) gives 1 result and a search on [permview ".NET 4"](https://www.google.com.sg/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=permview+%22.net+4%22&oq=permview+%22.net+4%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=hp.3...341.3725.0.3963.17.16.0.1.1.0.122.1070.12j4.16.0...0.0.8APH-fL10Mk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=3759d54e829f6878&biw=1366&bih=646) on Google gives... 9 results... Not of a great help so if I'm wondering if anyone is aware of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [SecAnnotate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2009/11/18/using-secannotate-to-analyze-your-assemblies-for-transparency-violations-an-example.aspx) is what you need since [CAS policy has been deprecated in .NET 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2010/02/24/so-is-cas-dead-in-net-4-or-what.aspx)?